# Differents between datatypes and Unit

Tags: java, scala

When Some cases in programming java or scala i got an error

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: String
```

that because of my domain or entity g/set methods got the error.

**Why i got this error? and**

**How i can overcome the error?**

for example i will show my entity and error codes in scala programming

domain

```
//@BeanProperty this line commented

@Column(name="USERNAME")
var userName:String=null

def getUserName() { 
  this.userName = userName 
}

//@BeanProperty
@Column(name="PASSWORD")
var password:String=null
def getPassword() { 
  this.password = password 
}
def setPassword(password:String) { 
  this.password = password 
}
```

and error got here

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )
  def loadUserByUsername(userName: String): UserDetails = {
    log.info("==>calling loadUserByUsername for the user " + userName);
    val userAccount: UserAccount = findUserAccount(userName);
    new User(userAccount.getUserName(), userAccount.getPassword(),
                     
    here error    ---^                       ^---- and here

     true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(userAccount));
  }
```

the compilation error shows :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - type mismatch; found : Unit 
     required: String
```

if you know the about these please share her..

With Regards MILANO :)

Comment: Your getters look like setters...

Comment: It would probably help if we knew the definition of `User` and `UserAccount`

Comment: @Thilo i don't know actually create setters and getters in scala

Comment: @milano but can you attach the code of User/UserAccount so we could look if there any issues with the .get* methods?

Comment: @Ingo UserAccount is my Domail and User is (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)

Comment: "i don't know actually create setters and getters in scala" That seems to be the problem here. Unit is similar to void in Java. And the "getter" you show looks "void" to me.

Comment: @Thilo how to avoid void in scala

Comment: maybe your "getter" should return a String?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Thilo already mentioned, your getters are setters. If you want to return e.g. the username you have to write something like this:

```
def getUsername():String = {
    this.username
}
```

Important is the **=** sign, which means, that the function will return (in this case the username ). `:String` defines the return type. Without the **=** it is like a `void` method in java, but your User object expects a String here, while your `getUsername()` is a function without return type (= Unit):

```
new User(userAccount.getUserName(), userAccount.getPassword())
```

Answer (score 3):

`Unit` means the same in this context as `void` in Java. That means: Your `getUserName` method returns nothing. Therefore, the compiler complains rightfully that it cannot assign the value of `getUserName` (of type `Unit`) to a `String` variable.

This is because there is an error in the `getUserName` method. It's not doing what you want it to do. And I propose that this is because a misunderstanding on how to return and assign values. Let's take a look on your example method first:

```
def getUserName() { 
  this.userName = userName 
}
```

First, note that in this context, `this.userName` and `userName` refer to the exact same instance variable. So, you are just overwriting the value of `userName` with the same value it contained before.

Here is what I assume you were thinking: "`this.userName` is the return value of `getUserName`, so I need to assign `userName` to it, so that the caller will get this value in return."

That's what I meant with the misunderstanding above. In Scala, you do not assign the return value of a function to a variable. Instead, you assign *the function itself* to a value. Look at this:

```
 def getUserName() = userName
```

This means exactly what you want.

More than that, in Scala, you typically leave out the `()` after the method name if the method does not modify the state of the object. That would mean we write:

```
def getUserName = userName
```

However, a method that changes the internal state of the object should have the `()`. Example:

```
def resetUserName() {userName = ""}
```

Now, what about the braces?

Let me give you an example. Assume you want to write a message to the console every time the getter is called. For debugging, maybe. Your method would look like this:

```
def getUserName = {
    println("User name was requested.")
    userName
}
```

You see a block of code here, after the equals sign. The return value of the function is the value of *the last statement that is executed inside this block*. Simple enough, we see it will be `userName`, which is what we want.

Like in Java, you can also use the `return` command in Scala. It is discouraged, but since it's supported by the syntax, I think it's good to mention it as well. Using the `return` statement, you can program your code just like you know it from Java:

```
def getUserName() {
    println("User name was requested.")
    return userName
}
```

Note the absence of the equals sign. When you explicitly use the `return` statement, you don't need the equals sign.

I hope that helps. I suggest further reading on the syntax of the Scala programming language. Any good Google search result will do. The resources linked on the Scala home page are recommendable. For more depth, I recommend the book on Scala by Martin Odersky. It's pretty good.

Comment: I'd add that {} without '=' is deprecated, Martin Odersky said lately that it was introduced to look more familar for Java newcomers but now it's only a point of confusion